# How do I echo a greater than sign in Cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping

How do I echo the "greater than" character in cmd? I would like to escape the "greater than" sign (`>`) because I need it to echo to another `.bat` file.

```
Echo net session>nul 2>&1>>2nd.bat
```

I need this output in 2nd.bat file:

```
net session>nul 2>&1
```

If I don't use quotes, crippled output is displayed in the prompt window.

I cannot use quotes because if I use them the output in my 2nd.bat becomes `"net session>nul 2>&1"` which doesn't run.

Comment: Some special chars must be escaped to print them literally instead of "doing their job". The escape character is `^`  (except for `%`, with is escaped with another `%`: `echo %%`): `echo ^>^&`

Comment: I've tried that but it too outputs in the prompt window. I've added spaces and I get this ```net session ^ nul 2 ^ &1```
output in the 2nd.bat file

Comment: `echo net session^>nul 2^>^&1 >>2nd.bat`

Comment: Now I'm getting this ```net session^ 2^ ``` in 2nd file.

Comment: No way for that to happen. You did something wrong.

Comment: I copied and pasted what you had sent. Is it due to the nul?

Comment: I verified again. Nothing wrong with my suggestion. Open a new `cmd` window and do `echo ^>`. It should show a literal `>`. If not, something is wrong with your computer.

Comment: Yeah maybe it's a bug cause I'm using dosbox right now.

Comment: it doesn't work in MS-DOS (6.22) either. You should remove the `cmd` flag, add the `dos` flag and add the info that you're using DOSBOX into the question itself to target your question to the right audience. (Glad that your Windows is ok `:)`)

Comment: Ok thanks it work I tried it in actual cmd! I was only testing out my code in Dosbox I was going to use it in actually windows.

Comment: I've tried it on cmd and it gives me this ```net session >nul 2>&```  I don't know why it doesn't write number 1.(not in dosbox)

Comment: My mistake of using dosbox for testing I thought there were basically the same but I need it to work in cmd and not in dosbox.

Comment: The Windows command line is based on `cmd.exe`, while MS-DOS is based on `command.com` (and DOSbox is (mostly) compatible with MS-DOS). They are very different things, although they look alike. There are new commands in `cmd` and a lot of "old" commands were significantly improved. While DOS scripts *should* work in `cmd` (some commands were removed), the vast majority of  `cmd` scripts (besides very basic ones like `echo hello world`) are practically guaranteed to fail in DOS.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple enough.

What you tried (the result of the comments):

```
echo net session^>nul 2^>^&1>2nd.bat
```

What I've tried (what works):

```
echo net session^>nul 2^>^&1 >2nd.bat
```